# Scrolling behaviour for apps (in general)

Tags: htc-desire, user-interface

I have a HTC Desire and I've realised there appears to be, for most apps (in general) 3 types of scrolling.

1. Drag/pull with finger and the contents scrolls (slowly) depending on how much you've moved your finger
2. 'Flick' your finger across the screen and the content scrolls (relatively fast) and slows down towards the end
3. "Do something" and the contents scrolls insanely fast - usually goes to the end of the content...

My question is what is what do I do to 'activate' #3?

Reason is, every now and then I somehow activate #3 (often when I don't want it) which makes it very annoying. But sometimes I do want to scroll insanely fast right to the bottom/top of the list/page but end up just flicking multiple times (very annoying again). Would be nice to be able to control/choose which scroll type I need.

Comment: I've only seen number 3 in one app: Tweetdeck. Pressing the button with the date/time on at the top of the list scrolls really fast to the top. It took me a while to discover this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also seen the 3 scrolling types you mention below, but it always seemed to me that the 3rd one was more a bug than a feature.

The HTC Desire (which I have too) is not known to have a great digitizer, the part of the screen that handles the finger positions and movements. Furthermore, it's not "multitouch", meaning it cannot handle properly more than 1 finger on the screen, although there are tries to support it but I've never seen it work constantly good. See [this page](http://wssoo.blogspot.com/2010/06/htc-desire-multi-touch-defect.html) for more proof.

It's true that it would be a nice feature, maybe on other phones with a better touchscreen and a further version of Android with more gestures supported. Why not for example scrolling down with 2 fingers would trigger a super-fast scroll or a "go to bottom" action?

Comment: Thanks for the link - it did occur to me that it might be a bug, but was secretly hoping it was a feature. Guess I'll have to try and find a way to reliably reproduce this 'buggy feature' :)